# Store list of Products in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am challenging myself to make a small web-shop, but I have faced a problem while storing an Order in my DB.

This is my Order class

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BasketProduct> BasketProducts { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

which stores BasketProducts(without int Id it did not want to work, but I don't know why it needs it)

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

In the BasketController, if the user clicks for a checkout I would like to create an order and put it into the DB

```
public ActionResult CreateOrder()
        {
            //GetCurrentBasket returns a basket of current session
            var baskItems = GetCurrentBasket().Items;

            Order order = new Order { BasketProducts = baskItems, UserName = User.Identity.Name };
            EFDbContext ent = new EFDbContext();
            ent.Orders.Add(order);
            ent.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Checkout", new { order = order });
        }
```

And in checkout Index method it should just take Order object and show all the products in it

```
       @model Domain.Elements.Order
       //some code omitted
       @foreach (var item in Model.BasketProducts)
       {
          <p>@item.Product.Name</p>
          <p>@item.Quantity</p>
       }
```

The problem is that in my DB(in Order table) it creates only Id and UserName, so I cannot retrieve any products current person ordered.

What mistake did I do, or maybe I am missing something to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the error I get right now.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What is GetCurrentBasket(), and how is it being populated? Are you posting your form from your View, to your CreateOrder() action?

Comment: Where exactly the exception occurs?

Comment: GetCurrentBasket returns a Basket object from current session. The index method does not do anything special: ActionResult Index(Order order){return View(order);}

Comment: The error occurs here Line 9:  @foreach (var item in Model.BasketProducts). It does not see the product list, because It is not stored in DB and I don't know why =/

Answer (score -1):

it seems like the issue is when you are saving to the database. I believe that when adding entities you'll want to add them to a particular DbSet on your content.
try something like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateOrder()
{
    //GetCurrentBasket returns a basket of current session
    var baskItems = GetCurrentBasket().Items;

    var context = new EFDbContext();
    var orders = context.GetDbSet<Order>();

    var order = orders.Create(); //use the DbSet to create your new entity
    order.BasketProducts = baskItems;
    order.UserName = User.Identity.Name;

    orders.Add(order);

    try
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch(DatabaseException ex)
    {
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Checkout", new { order = order });
 }
```

I've wrapped your Context.SaveChanges() call in a try/catch. I typically do this if I have an error saving to the db, that way I can debug and step through it, any database level exceptions will be caught and you can see whats going on.

Comment: unfortunately the error remains the same..
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.